# On arrow function bodies, whats the difference between using brackets, placing direclty the condition, or using pharentesis?

Tags: javascript, function

In my years of JS development I've seen the following examples:

```
let a = () => console.log("a");
let b = () => { console.log("b"); }
let c = () => (console.log("c"));
```

I know the difference between the first two options, but the last one always seem'd a little off to me. I've also tried to do the following, which surprisingly works:

```
let c = () => (console.log("c1"), console.log("c2")); // Outputs both console logs.
```

And also this:

```
let c = () => (1, 2, 3, 4 ,5);
let x  = c(); // 5
```

I've searched about this way of defining function bodies, yet I'm not satisfied with what I have found since every example I've stumbled on was poorly explained.

Can anyone please explain to me a bit more in-depth the difference between the three examples, and also what's special about the last one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `=>` functions are fairly recent, your years of JavaScript experience can't number very many :) Also traditional functions are required in a variety of circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `let c = () => (console.log("c"))`
>
> I know the difference between the first two options, but the last one always seem'd a little off to me.

Arrow syntax allows you to return the value of the expression directly without having to enclose in curly braces and using a `return` statement. In the example above, enclosing the value (returned by `console.log`) in brackets does not change its value.

> And also this:
>
> `let c = () => (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`

What you are seeing is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in action. It will return the value of the last operand, which is why `c` returns `5`.

> I've also tried to do the following, which surprisingly works:
>
> `let c = () => (console.log("c1"), console.log("c2")); // Outputs both console log`

In this case, both expressions are evaluated, and thus both strings are logged. However, the expression yields a value of `undefined`, since `console.log` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I did not know about this operator until now, thanks for explaining it to me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're talking *specifically* about arrow (`=>`) functions. Traditional functions must have a body enclosed in `{ }`.

An arrow function *can* have a traditional body enclosed in `{ }`. It can also have a single expression as its body, in which case the result of evaluating the expression is implicitly the return value. Given that, note that *any* expression in JavaScript in any context can be enclosed in parentheses `( )` and the value is the same as the enclosed expression.

The comma effect is the operator in the JavaScript expression grammar `,`, which allows disparate expressions to be chained together into a list that, syntactically, is still a single expression. The comma operator is useful sometimes because expressions can have side-effects; for example, a function call is an expression, and a function call may do almost anything. The value of a list of expressions in a comma operator list is the value of the last one of the expressions after evaluation.

Comment: The only weirdness with `( )` enclosed expressions has to do with references to functions that are computed within parentheses. That's out of the scope of this question I think.

Comment: I see, thanks! It all makes sense now :).